# Get checked values of checkbox list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of checkbox with the name `etapes`. I'd like to get all the checked `etapes`'s value and store it in a single string.

So tried this :

```
$('[name="etapes"]:checked').each(function() {
    indexer = indexer + 1;
    if (indexer == 1) selectedEtapes = $(this).val();
    else selectedEtapes = selectedEtapes + "," + $(this).val();
});
```

but it didn't work. SO how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier solution is to use [**`jQuery.map`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```js
var mapped = $('[name="etapes"]:checked').map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
console.log(mapped.join(','));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="etapes" value="Ouverte1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="etapes" value="Ouverte2">
<input type="checkbox" name="etapes" value="Ouverte3" checked>
```

**Fix for your code:**

You never accepted `index` argument,

```js
var selectedEtapes = '';
$('[name="etapes"]:checked').each(function(index) {
  if (!index) selectedEtapes += $(this).val();
  else selectedEtapes += "," + $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: I have for example this checkbox  `<input type="checkbox" name="etapes" value="Ouverte" checked="checked">` when I tried your solution I get a blank

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `map()` method like following.

```js
var str = $('[name="etapes"]:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get().join();

console.log(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="etapes" value="Ouverte1" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="etapes" value="Ouverte2">
<input type="checkbox" name="etapes" value="Ouverte3" checked="checked">
<input type="checkbox" name="etapes" value="Ouverte4" checked="checked">
```

Comment: I have a list of checkbox like this  `<input type="checkbox" name="etapes" value="Ouverte" checked="checked">`. Yout proposition give me a blank string

Comment: It should work. See updated code snippet. @LamloumiAfif